# How to enable highlight .cu CUDA files in PyCharm?

Tags: cuda, pycharm

I want PyCharm to correctly highlight CUDA files. But there is no plugin for it.

Is there any better way than just registering a ***.cu** pattern in [**Settings->Editor->Files Types**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62CH8.png) under **C/C++** file type?

Comment: Jetbrains hasn't support cuda officially now. You can see others' solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980645/enable-code-indexing-of-cuda-in-clion).

Comment: @halfelf Thanks.